# Can any framework project use Struts-taglib

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, struts, jsp-tags

I have read [here](http://www.techinfopad.com/spring/100300104-about-spring-mvc-vs-struts.html) that one disadvantage that some may find with using Spring MVC over Struts is that Struts has tags that output HTML code, while Spring has tags that don't generate HTML.

My question is can't you just use the Struts tag-lib in a Spring MVC project (or any other kind of framework project), by dropping the right jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Any clarification is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring does integrate with Struts.  It's not as easy as just dropping the JAR and its dependencies; you have to [configure Spring](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/70-integrating-struts-with-spring-1.html) to know about Struts.